# are these norms equivalent?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

If it is known that $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\geq \alpha^2|\xi|^2$, where $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,...,\xi_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then can it be said that $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}$ is an equivalent norm to the usual norm of the Sobolev space $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$?. Note that $a_{ij}$ are all bounded measurable functions.

Comment: Is $(a^{-1})_{ij}$ also bounded and measurable?

Comment: No information is available on the $1/a_{ij}$'s though.

Comment: Yes, since also $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\leq \beta^2|\xi|^2$ for large enough $\beta$ depending on $n$ and suprema of  $a_{ij}$'s.

Comment: Ah, yes, Fedor is right. Since the inequality you gave actually bounds $a_{ij}$ from below, the operator norm of $(a^{-1})_{ij}$ (the components of the inverse matrix, not the inverses of the matrix elements) should be bounded by $1/\alpha^2$ (and maybe a constant depending on $n$).

Comment: I just noticed that the triangle inequality for the 'norm' on $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ defined by $||u||_{1,2}=(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j})^{1/2}$ is the difficult part. There are two extra terms which creeps in and that is what is the root cause of the difficulty. Can you please at least give me a hint so that I can go ahead?.

Comment: At first, you miss $\int$ in your formula for the norm.  At second, your norm is Hilbert norm for a positive-definite inner product $\langle u,v\rangle=\int \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}$. This guarantees the triangle inequality.